# Speed up mouse wheel in jScrollPane (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a div with a fixed height and in it a ul-list and many li-items. I apply to the div a jScrollPane for which I want to customize the appearance of the scrollbar. My code is like:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myDiv').jScrollPane( { showArrows: true, arrowScrollOnHover: true, wheelSpeed: 120 });
});
```

As jScrollPane I use the scripts of http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com and it is kind of working. But the speed of the mouse wheel (velocity of scrolling) is much too slow although I tried to set the speed up as you can see in my example above.

Does anybody has had the same effect and can give me a hint how I can speed it up?

Comment: I think it'd be best to change the correct answer to Sargin Sargin's, if that also works for you. It's a better way of setting a custom scroll rate for an instance of the plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the jquery.jscrollpane.js (or even .min.js file), find "mouseWheelSpeed" in the "defaults". This was 3 for me originally, I bumped it up to 30. Perhaps it is 3 or 30 pixles/click.

**Edit**

Sargin Sargin's answer is probably better for most cases. Given his solution, editing the plugin file would only make sense if you wanted to set a new default for reuse around a site. You'd also need to make note of changes made so that you don't lose your customisation when you update the file.

Comment: Whoppa! Thanks andrewb. That did it!

Comment: I found that IE scrolled 31px, Webkit (Opera, Safari, Chrome) scrolled 33px, and FF scrolled 42px. There's no way of detecting the actual delta except by capturing a scroll event and measuring the `scrollTop` value.

Answer (score 16):

You have to define the wheel speed when you initialize the plugin like this:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    mouseWheelSpeed: 50
});
```

Comment: Notice that `mouseWheelSpeed` won't work in IE8 or below if you use jquery.mousewheel.js greater than 3.1.5 (jScrollPane current version: 2.0.21)